When a Laplace-Stieltjes transform is continuous in an M/G/1 system?
I have an M/G/1 system where the service distribution is bounded on a finite support and continuous. The distribution of the sojourn time in the system is given by the Laplace-Stieltjes transform. I would like to know if, and when, this distribution is continuous under the assumptions of my problem.
